# GoogleFitの歩数管理の仕様について

Tags: android

GoogleFitから歩数を取得するアプリを開発していますが、以下のGoogleFitの仕様について、ご存じの方がいましたら、教えていただけますでしょうか？

①GoogleFitアプリとFitbitなどのウェアブルデバイスを連携した場合、GoogleFit内での歩数管理の仕様を教えていただきたい。
　例えば、Fitbitをfittofitアプリを利用してGoogleFitに連携した場合、
　GoogleFitアプリ上の歩数詳細には特に「fitbit」「fittofit」という表示がされていないので、歩数の計測元が端末自体なのか、
　Fitbitなのかわからないです。
　また、別のデバイスXiaomiの連携アプリ「Mifit」で歩数連携を行うと「Mifit」とGoogleFit側にも計測元が表示されます。
　この、計測元が表示される、されない、についての条件など、仕様を教えていただけますでしょうか？

②歩数計測を行ってGoogleFitアプリに歩数が反映されるまでに、タイムラグがありますが、
　場合によっては、10分以上反映にかかることがあります。
　最大でどのくらいの時間発生しますでしょうか？
　また、このタイムラグはなぜ発生するのでしょうか？

③GoogleFitのdeviceTypeについて設定の仕様をご教示ください。
どのdeviceTypeのデータを取得するか判断するために利用します。
※WearOSはウェアラブル、それ以外のウェアラブルから連携するアプリ（FittoFit等）は
　アプリとして連携される、等。
上記のデバイスタイプの記載（ウェアラブルとかは正式なdeviceTypeで教えていただきたいです)